# Type narrowing with generic union types

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to define two types that have the following shape

```
type A<T> = { message: string, data: T };
type B<T> = { age: number, properties: T };

type C<T> = A<T> | B<T>;

const x = {} as unknown as C<number>;

if (x.message) { // <--- HERE
 // 'x' should be of type A
}
```

But I'm not getting a type inference/narrowing here, is this construction possible? and if so, what am I doing wrong here?

**Typescript Playground**:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggPAFQHxQLxQN5QLYQM54CGA5hAFxR7ABOAlgHbEA0UAJocIRQlAL4DcAKFCQoAIUQp0WEuSj0ArtgBGEaizDUA9pGrBa+bnyHDw0AMKS0sKwB9xkkwGMt9KlAAe1jLyiE8UAr0ANb0WgDu9H4BlooqakgmtABmUAAUHgB0uASyAJSYglBQgrxAA

Comment: I think the reasoning behind this is that property can have getters with side effects. So Typescript is paranoid about letting you access potentially undefined properties.

Comment: @AlexWayne Thanks for that explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`in`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) operator for type narrowing:

```
if ('message' in x) {
  x.data
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=2&pln=8&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggPAFQHxQLxQN5QLYQM54CGA5hAFxR7ABOAlgHbEA0UAJocIRQlAL4DcAKFCQoAIUQp0WEuSj0ArtgBGEaizDUA9pGrBa+bnyHDw0AMKS0sKwB9xkkwGMt9KlAAe1jLyiE8UAr0ANb0WgDu9H4BlooqakgmtABmUAAUAOS4BLIZUAyeAJSYglCeAHTsnIK8QA)